# How can I get "caller expression" of the parameter passed to the method, not the value of it in C#?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static void MyMethod( Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> table /* ... more args ... */ )
{
    // Inside this method body, I want to get the caller expression (that is GetDynamicDictionaryValue() in this case), not the value of 'table' parameter.
}
```

In another file, where I call above method (MyMethod):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> GetDynamicDictionaryValue()
{
    // This returns dynamic dictionary...
}

public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    // This is the caller to MyMethod.
    MyMethod( table: GetDynamicDictionaryValue() /* ... */ );
}
```

(I have wrote above sample code without testing it. If there are any mistakes, I will fix them.)

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, where the problem is, and what you tried to solve it..

Comment: @nozzleman: Well, I don't know how to exactly call this, that's the main problem. Above I have simplest version of my problem.. I really can't simplify this.. Read comments in the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - parameters in C# passed by value and there is no way for method to know how particular parameter was computed.

You can instead pass function that compute parameter or [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to build it yourself (similar to LINQ-to-SQL).

Sample showing how to pass function:

```
public static void MyMethod( Func<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>> tableArgCreator,
 /* ... more args ... */ )
{
    var table = tableArgCreator();
    ...
}

MyMethod( table: GetDynamicDictionaryValue, /* ... */ );
```

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. Thanks for help.